# Blazor WASM with Azure AD Login pop up flashing and disappearing

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor

I have a Blazor WASM app with Azure AD Authentication. I use Visual Studio as IDE and use Browserlink to test before deploying to Azure App Service.

This morning (was fine yesterday) when I try to use the Browserlink "View in Browser", the website comes up properly in localhost, but when I click the Login button, the microsoft authentication window (pop up) flashes up and then disappears and I can't see it or get to it in any way.

I deployed the exact same current application to Azure App Service and the authentication window comes up as expected with no issues. I do have the localhost address in the Azure portal under the App registrations authentication section and am using https for all calls.

Not sure what else to check. Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like it loading the original config still which can be cached. Have your tried the good ole CTRL-F5.

Comment: I noticed the in the browser's console it was saying "These requirements were not met: RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (...)". Could it be that a role was changed?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it was the issue with Internet explorer as there are [known issues](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/internet-explorer.md#popups) with pop-up windows on Internet Explorer.

During sign in, to acquire tokens using MSAL.js, the library first attempt a silent token request using the acquireTokenSilent method and checks the cache in browser storage to see if a valid token exists and returns it.See if it is not clearing the cache and has azure AD Session is found already which may not redirect or pop up for login.

If no valid token is in the cache, it sends a silent token request to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) from a hidden iframe . However, ***if no valid Azure AD Session exists, silent token request fails and user can be either provided with a login popup or redirect***.

In your case, at the first launch of the application, when no valid token in the cache or valid Azure AD Session is found, silent token request fails and you are presented with the login popup but subsequent logins work without login popup.

***[Pop up and redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#choosing-between-a-pop-up-or-redirect-experience)***

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what was going on. I had tried the hard refresh and empty cache option as well as a reboot.
It seems to have fixed itself as today was fine. Thank you for your responses.